# How to create Jacoco code coverage report from jacoco.exec binary file that is generated from JAR file?

Tags: command-line-interface, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have been looking to generate a code coverage report from the jar build file, with jacoco.

I found this command

```
java -jar jacococli.jar dump [--address <address>] --destfile <path> [--help] [--port <port>] [--quiet] [--reset] [--retry <count>]
```

to make it work but have no idea how to generate jacococli.jar .
I normally added as dependency but nothing happened.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.cli</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found this command
>
> ```
> java -jar jacococli.jar dump [--address <address>] --destfile <path> [--help] [--port <port>] [--quiet] [--reset] [--retry <count>]
> ```
>
> ... added as dependecy but nothing happened

`jacococli.jar` is not intended to be used as a dependency - command is shown in JaCoCo documentation on page https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html
which states

> JaCoCo comes with a command line interface to perform basic operations **from the command line**.

and later also states

> For more sophisticated usage especially with larger projects please use our **[integrations](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/integrations.html) with various build tools**.

among integrations there is `jacoco-maven-plugin` for generation of report using Maven, documentation of this plugin available on page https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html

---

To use `jacococli.jar` for generation of report from `jacoco.exec` file for `your.jar` file

1. download `zip` distribution of JaCoCo from https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/
2. extract it for example into directory `jacoco`, `jacococli.jar` will be in `jacoco/lib/jacococli.jar`
3. open command line in this directory and execute

```
java -jar lib/jacococli.jar report path/to/jacoco.exec --classfiles path/to/your.jar --html path/for/report
```

4. HTML report will be in directory `path/for/report`

Comment: You just duplicated what i have written there and showed the link of documentation that i have already typed there as a command.. :/

Comment: See updated answer. And please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to better formulate your questions in future, so that they can be understood correctly by other people.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. Is there a way to use one time --classfiles attribute for more than one class files? @Godin Currently if i want two file for instance every time i have to type --classfile class1 --classfile class2

Comment: `--classfiles` parameter accepts individual `class` files, as well as `jar` files containing `class` files, as well as directories containing `jar` files and `class` files, and indeed can be specified multiple times